# extract lines from large tab delimited file using a list

Tags: command-line, awk, grep

I have a large tab file with 15 columns (FILE1) and a list (FILE2) of names which should appear in the table. The problem is the name may appear in columns 4 to 10 in FILE1 and it may not be a case match.

I want a command which searches line for a hit and then print the whole line. Preferably this would not be case sensitive and would not print lines where the names in FILE2 are part of a larger word.

I have tried the following:

```
grep -Fwf FILE2 FILE1 > out 
xargs -I {} grep "^{}" FILE1 < FILE2 > out
```

the first just copies FILE1 into out. The second give a blank out file.

I've also tried a few `awk` commands which will either give an empty out file or as above copy FILE1. I'm trying to improve my Linux skills at the moment so if possible, if you explain your method I would be very grateful.

File1

```
tax_id GeneID  Symbol  LocusTag        Synonyms        dbXrefs chromosome      map_location    description     type_of_gene    Symbol_from_nomenclature_authority      Full_name_from_nomenclature_authority Nomenclature_status      Other_designations      Modification_date
7       5692769 NEWENTRY        -       -       -       -       -       Record to support submission of GeneRIFs for a gene not in Gene (Azotirhizobium caulinodans.  Use when strain, subtype, isolate, etc. is unspecified, or when different from all specified ones in Gene.).     other   -       -       -       -       20160818
9       1246500 repA1   pLeuDn_01       -       -       -       -       putative replication-associated protein protein-coding  -       -       -       -       20160813
9       1246501 repA2   pLeuDn_03       -       -       -       -       putative replication-associated protein protein-coding  -       -       -       -       20160716
9       1246502 leuA    pLeuDn_04       -       -       -       -       2-isopropylmalate synthase      protein-coding  -       -       -       -       20160903
9       1246503 leuB    pLeuDn_05       -       -       -       -       3-isopropylmalate dehydrogenase protein-coding  -       -       -       -       20150520
9       1246504 leuC    pLeuDn_06       -       -       -       -       isopropylmalate isomerase large subunit protein-coding  -       -       -       -       20160806
9       1246505 leuD    pLeuDn_07       -       -       -       -       isopropylmalate isomerase small subunit protein-coding  -       -       -       -       20160730
9       1246509 ibp     pBPS1_01        -       -       -       -       Ibp protein     protein-coding  -       -       -       -       20150801
9       1246510 repA1   pBPS1_02        -       -       -       -       repA1 protein   protein-coding  -       -       -       -       20160813
```

File2

```
sacX
arcB
metB
sprT
adrB_2
fadD
trpC
ansP2
group_1428
plsX
repA
```

Comment: show fragments of your `FILE1` and `FILE2`

Comment: please, post your inputs as text, not images. `cat file1` , then select the output, copy-paste

Comment: Yes, posting images of text is basically useless. We need to be able to copy what you give us to our machines and test our solutions. So, please [edit] your question, and paste the data you show in the images as text. Also show us the output you would want to see from that data, that way we're sure we'll give you useful solutions.

Comment: The example above is just a snapshot. File1 contains 1104158 rows.

Comment: The example above is just a snapshot. File1 contains 1104158 rows. I would like to output lines where if repA was found in any column, the line/row is printed into a new file.

Comment: take the first 10 with `head file` command

Comment: Yes that is what I have above although its not printing clearly

Comment: The `grep` solution works here for your example. It doesn't give output because your sample doesn't have matches. If you want to have the `repA1` and `repA2` lines matched, leave away the `w` option. If you want to match case insensitive, add `i` option.

Comment: Make a test removing the `w` flag from your grep. With `-w` you match words, thus `repA` will not match `repA1`. By removing `-w` you will match `repA1`, but you will also match entries like `datarepA1234567890`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou It still creates a copy of FILE1 for me.

Comment: @Philippos there are matches between my list and the table. the data provided here is just a snapshot. I have managed to get an R code to work but the case sensitivity issue is preventing all the hit being recorded.

Comment: Did you try option `i` for grep? There shouldn't be an case sensitivity issue then. If you get a copy of FILE1, please check whether you have an empty line in FILE2

Comment: @Philippos you were right there were a few trailing blank lines I have removed them and it is working great now.

Comment: Can you write an answer to your own question and accept it, so other users finding this question don't have to read through the whole comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer in comments above**
see @Philippos and @George Vasiliou replies

Briefly the answer is  `grep -Fwf FILE2 FILE1 > out`

I was having an issue whereby then I executed the command it would copy FILE1. This was occurring because of trailing blank lines in FILE2. When I removed these the command worked perfectly.

As some of my text in the files may not match case-wise I included -i in the above command.

Thanks to all who helped.

Comment: This will fail (return false positives) if the description field has something like `similar to metB` in it.

Comment: I don't quite get your meaning? If the command find hits in the description column rather than symbol I want those too, as not all the gene names are present in the symbol column. This would still be valid to me along as it does not report textmetBtest,

Comment: In that case, it's fine.